# Prevent an app crash due to a slow connection when retrieving a remote file

Tags: ios

I am currently using a function in my app's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` that retrieves a file, saves it to the application directory.

I have found that when there is a weak connection the app will crash when this is happening. I read that there is a 20 second time limit Apple allows before crashing the app. Is this correct? If so, I believe this is causing my issue as the app works flawlessly with the exception of being on a very weak connection.

How could I modify my logic below to try and compensate for this?

```c
- (void)writeJsonToFile
{   
//applications Documents dirctory path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//live json data url
NSString *stringURL = @"http://link-to-my-data.json";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

//attempt to download live data
if (urlData)
{   
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"data.json"];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
//copy data from initial package into the applications Documents folder
else
{
    //file to write to
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"data.json"];

    //file to copy from
    NSString *json = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"html/data" ];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:json options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //write file to device
    [jsonData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to run this sort of thing on the main thread: I assume you are - basically, you'll block the entire UI while you wait for the network operation to complete.

`dataWithContentsOfURL` is not a good idea for this sort of thing. It will be much better to use `NSURLConnection` or one of the wrapper libraries like `AFNetworking`, because you can handle cases like when the connection times out gracefully.

These libraries also have built-in methods to asynchronously download the data, which prevents the main UI thread from being locked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw in my thread use. This is my first app so I am still adjusting to the concepts of threading and memory management. After rethinking my current implementation of this method, I intend to update the data in the background after the app has launched. Your answer was similar to @SVGreg however you made the suggestion first so the answer is awarded here.

Answer (score 1):

When is this downloaded data needed?

Depending on the answer, maybe you can call the method inside a thread. This will prevent the main thread from blocking.

Even if the data is needed from the beginning, you can just create a loader and download the file in the background, then make the app active after the file is downloaded.

Comment: My app will require the data to be present before it can run. I am shipping the app with a local copy of the data file in the bundle so I will make use of the local data on first run and then retrieve any updates in the background. This seems like the best approach since I won't have to leave the app in an inactive state while I wait on the fresh data.

Comment: This sounds as a good solution. But still reconsider which is the best way for you to download the file as lxt and SVGreg wrote. Another solution is to use ASIHTTPRequest, but this might be too overwhelming for just downloading one file which i think will not be of a very large size.

Answer (score 1):

I think to be more independent from internal implementation of `NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` you should implement you own download class based on `NSURLConnection`.

**The links to read:**

[URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)

[NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection)

[NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate)

So you can catch all connection errors by your code and implement right behavior in this case.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion and supporting links. I will evaluate and determine if this is the route I want to proceed with.